# How can I read in a JSON file and pass it in the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, amazon-connect

I'm implementing a script that will be used to update a contact flow in AWS Connect. I have a JSON file definining the flow, which is managed separately in source control. I want to implement a script using the aws connect api to update the flow using the AWS CLI endpoint.

```
INSTANCE_ID=123456-789
CONTACT_ID=9876-1234
aws connect update-contact-flow-content \
  --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID \
  --contact-flow-id $CONTACT_ID \
  --content '$(cat contactflow.json | jq -c )'
```

However, reading it in like this doesn't properly escape the JSON. How can I read in this data in a way that properly escapes it, or otherwise passes the full JSON file to AWS?

Comment: Using `--content file://contactflow.json` should work as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html). Have you tried that?

Comment: In any case, single quotes prevent expansion, try double quotes instead.

Comment: @Marcin that notation does the job. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution is to use `file://` notation to read json form the file as explained in aws format docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html):

```
--content file://contactflow.json
```